# Jersey client upload progress

Tags: java, upload, jersey

I have a jersey client that need to upload a file big enough to require a progress bar.
The problem is that, for an upload that requires some minutes, i see the bytes transfered to go to 100% **as soon as the application has started**. Then it takes some minutes to print the "on finished" string.
 *It is as if the bytes were sent to a buffer, and i was reading the transfert-to-the buffer speed instead of the actual upload speed*. This makes the progress bar useless.

This is the very simple code:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource resource = client.resource("www.myrestserver.com/uploads");
WebResource.Builder builder = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
FileDataBodyPart fdbp = new FileDataBodyPart("data.zip", new File("data.zip"));
BodyPart bp = multiPart.bodyPart(fdbp);
String response = builder.post(String.class, multiPart);
```

To get progress state i've added a ContainerListener filter, obviouslt before calling builder.post:

```
final ContainerListener containerListener = new ContainerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSent(long delta, long bytes) {
            System.out.println(delta + " : " + long);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
            System.out.println("on finish");
        }

    };

    OnStartConnectionListener connectionListenerFactory = new OnStartConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public ContainerListener onStart(ClientRequest cr) {
            return containerListener;
        }

    };

    resource.addFilter(new ConnectionListenerFilter(connectionListenerFactory));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be enough to provide you own MessageBodyWriter for java.io.File which fires some events or notifies some listeners as progress changes

```
@Provider()
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public class MyFileProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<File> {

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return File.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public void writeTo(File t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation annotations[], MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(t);
        try {
            int read;
            final byte[] data = new byte[ReaderWriter.BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                entityStream.write(data, 0, read);
                // fire some event as progress changes
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(File t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return t.length();
    }
}
```

and to make your client application uses this new provider simply:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(MyFileProvider.class);
```

or

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
MyFileProvider myProvider = new MyFileProvider ();
cc.getSingletons().add(myProvider);
```

You would have to also include some algorithm to recognize which file is transfered when receiving progress events.

**Edited:**

I just found that by default HTTPUrlConnection uses buffering. And to disable buffering you could do couple of things:

1. httpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(chunklength) - disables buffering and uses chunked transfer encoding to send request
2. httpUrlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength) - disables buffering and but ads some constraints to streaming: exact number of bytes must be sent

So I suggest the final solution to your problem uses 1st option and would look like this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(MyFileProvider.class);
URLConnectionClientHandler clientHandler = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new HttpURLConnectionFactory() {
     @Override
     public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
           HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                return connection;
            }
});
Client client = new Client(clientHandler, config);
```

Comment: thanks Tomasz, this answer is very good. The fact that you've provided two ways to configure the client is really admirable and explanatory. unfortunatly, the problem persists. I just put a System.out.println(...) after entityStream.write, but the result is that I write big files (>10MB) in a fraction of second, and then it freezes while the "real" upload happens. The fact that happens also with this solution means that the problem is elsewhere. For your answer, i cannot accept it but i can start another specific question where i'll be glad to mark it as correct. :-)

Comment: I tryed also to add a entityStream.flush(); after entityStream.write (...) in order to force an actual writing to socket instead of just writing on buffer. Same result :-(

Comment: ok, great answer, it works. in both ways, that is with listeners and with custom file provider. Perhaps it should be emphasized that the solution is the second part, maybe moving it at the top. The File Provider is interesting as an alternative to listeners. Also, it helps to clarify the jersey architecture, so i would keep it, but not as a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

In Jersey 2.X, i've used a **WriterInterceptor** to wrap the output stream with a subclass of Apache Commons IO CountingOutputStream that tracks the writing and notify my upload progress code (not shown).

```
public class UploadMonitorInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        // the original outputstream jersey writes with
        final OutputStream os = context.getOutputStream();

        // you can use Jersey's target/builder properties or 
        // special headers to set identifiers of the source of the stream
        // and other info needed for progress monitoring
        String id = (String) context.getProperty("id");
        long fileSize = (long) context.getProperty("fileSize");

        // subclass of counting stream which will notify my progress
        // indicators.
        context.setOutputStream(new MyCountingOutputStream(os, id, fileSize));

        // proceed with any other interceptors
        context.proceed();
    }

}
```

I then registered this interceptor with the client, or with specific targets where you want to use the interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used David's answer. However, I would like to extend on it:

The following `aroundWriteTo` implementation of my `WriterInterceptor` shows how a panel (or similar) can also be passed to the `CountingOutputStream`:

```java
@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException
{
  final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();

  long fileSize = (long) context.getProperty(FILE_SIZE_PROPERTY_NAME);

  context.setOutputStream(new ProgressFileUploadStream(outputStream, fileSize,
      (progressPanel) context
          .getProperty(PROGRESS_PANEL_PROPERTY_NAME)));

  context.proceed();
}
```

The `afterWrite` of the `CountingOutputStream` can then set the progress:

```java
@Override
protected void afterWrite(int n)
{
  double percent = ((double) getByteCount() / fileSize);
  progressPanel.setValue((int) (percent * 100));
}
```

The properties can be set on the `Invocation.Builder` object:

```java
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
invocationBuilder.property(
    UploadMonitorInterceptor.FILE_SIZE_PROPERTY_NAME, newFile.length());
invocationBuilder.property(
    UploadMonitorInterceptor.PROGRESS_PANEL_PROPERTY_NAME,      
    progressPanel);
```

**Perhaps the most important addition to David's answer and the reason why I decided to post my own is the following code:**

```java
client.property(ClientProperties.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, 1024);
client.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, "CHUNKED");
```

The `client` object is the the `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`.

**It is essential to disable buffering also with the `WriterInterceptor` approach. Above code is a straightforward way to do this with Jersey 2.x**