# Upload file via streaming using Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, jersey, streaming

I am trying to create a file upload API using Jersey. I would like to obtain details about the upload progress in the server side (is it possible?). Searching the web, the suggestion was to use stream to transfer the file. But... even was described below, the server just to execute the "putFile" method after the file arrives completely. Another problem is that these code only works to small files, when I try a file greater than 40mb

```
@Path("/file")
public class LargeUpload {

private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "/Users/diego/Documents/uploads/";

@PUT
@Path("/upload/{attachmentName}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response putFile(@PathParam("attachmentName") String attachmentName,
                         InputStream fileInputStream) throws Throwable {

    String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + attachmentName;

    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    String output = "File saved to server location : ";

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}


// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.property(ClientProperties.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, 1024);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    File fileName = new File("/Users/diego/Movies/ff.mp4");
    InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    String sContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName.getName()+"\"";

    Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("upload-controller/webapi/file/upload/"+fileName.getName()).
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("Content-Disposition", sContentDisposition).
            put(Entity.entity(fileInStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    System.out.println(response);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey client upload progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584791/jersey-client-upload-progress)

Comment: The problem is that this solution works on the client side, creating a listener. I'm looking for this control on the server side... That is why I'm using streaming...

Comment: So create a MessageBodyReader instead.

Comment: Do you have any example?