# Are POST requests with Content-Disposition header supported in Postman?

Tags: rest, request, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I did some research both in the Postman GUI (auto-completion for request headers which does not offer "Content-Disposition") and in learning.postman.com/docs and there is no mention of "Content-Disposition" request header.  I am using this request header in a POST request to upload a PDF file to an existing document.  The operation is successful.  But this is currently being done in a Jersey REST client Java project.  I'm trying to create a similar POST REST request in Postman as part of a test collection.

Any workaround for this or just not supported?  The "standard" multipart/form-data example cited everywhere and including Postman docs/examples is not supported by this upload POST API.

The Java/REST client code was based on this SO code: [Upload file via streaming using Jersey 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704406/upload-file-via-streaming-using-jersey-2) only difference in my client I am using "application/pdf" as MediaType.