# Track file upload progress with WriterInterceptor

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to create a progress bar which shows the progress of a file upload from a client with jersey 2.22. I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31347039/5183341) and used a `WriteInterceptor` to wrap the `OutputStream` into a `CountingOutputStream`.

The problem now is that as soon as the file upload starts the full byte count gets printed to the console within one second. But then nothing happens for a long time till the upload finishes.

I am pretty sure I am just tracking the bytes written to a buffer on the client side with this solution (and not the bytes which are really sent to the host).

**So my questions is**: Am I misunderstanding something here? Or is it simply not possible to track the sent bytes from a client to a host?

```
public class UploadMonitorInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final OutputStream os = context.getOutputStream();                    

        context.setOutputStream(new MyCountingOutputStream(os));

        context.proceed();          
    }
}
```

The MyCountingOutputStream class:

```
public class MyCountingOutputStream extends CountingOutputStream {
    public MyCountingOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b,int st,int end) throws IOException {
        super.write(b,st,end);
        System.out.println("ByteCount:"+end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Writer interceptor is for outbound. ReaderInterceptor is for inbound.

Comment: @peeskillet yea thats true. But I want upload a file from the client side to the host and track the upload progress on the client side too. So WriterInterceptor should be correct.. or not ?

Comment: Oh. I don't know, I've never implemented such thing. Would be something that I'd have to do some deep pondering on :-)

Comment: @peeskillet oh, I thought it is a totally basic thing to get the progress of a file upload :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem. I was in fact just tracking the write commands of the stream into a buffer. What I did now is setting `chunkedStreamingMode` to `1024`. And then I just needed to set the received provider from the following function as a connector for the client.

```
private static HttpUrlConnectorProvider buildHttpUrlConnectorProvider(){
             HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory factory = new HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpURLConnection getConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                        HttpURLConnection result = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        result.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                        return result;
                    }
                };
             return new HttpUrlConnectorProvider().connectionFactory(factory);
        }
```

As far as I understood it, buffering gets disabled if `chunkedStreamingMode` is set.